# Не срабатывает функция!

Tags: jquery, javascript

Уважаемые кодеры js подскажите в чем проблема. Первая функция срабатывает, а вторая, которая заменяет содержимое не срабатывает, почему?

```
<script>
   var ac = '<div onClick="b();">Действие_2</div>';

   function a() 
    {   
     $('#description').html( "Текст_1" );
     $('#active').html( ac );
    }

    function b()
    {
     $('#description').html( "Текст_2" );
    }

  </script>

        <div id="active">
<div onClick="a();">Действие</div>            
           </div>
<div id="description">текст</div>
```

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

что за браузер? в хроме всё срабаывает http://jsfiddle.net/utk8K/

Comment: подтверждаю работоспособность в Опере